# Similar thing to regex groups in Lua?

Tags: regex, lua

I have a log with lines like this:

```
Jun 21 06:25:07 172.25.1.1 kernel: DROP IN=ppp0 OUT= MAC= SRC=206.221.177.2 DST=185.79.95.179 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=239 ID=25584 PROTO=TCP SPT=40001 DPT=58571 SEQ=1145952392 ACK=0 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

I'd like to extract some information from it: the date, the source IP etc.
With a regexp I can do it (in python or perl): `'^(... ..) .* DROP .* SRC=(\S+)'`
But how can I do this in Lua?

Comment: `date,ip = string.match(s, "^(%w+ %d+ %d%d:%d%d:%d%d) .* DROP .* SRC=(%S+)")`? See https://ideone.com/2uASKu

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks, I just started learning Lua and I read, there is no regex. It looks perfext for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a solution based on [`string.match`](http://lua-users.org/wiki/PatternsTutorial):

```
local s = "Jun 21 06:25:07 172.25.1.1 kernel: DROP IN=ppp0 OUT= MAC= SRC=206.221.177.2 DST=185.79.95.179 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=239 ID=25584 PROTO=TCP SPT=40001 DPT=58571 SEQ=1145952392 ACK=0 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 ]"
date,ip = string.match(s, "^(%w+ %d+ %d%d:%d%d:%d%d) .* DROP .* SRC=(%S+)")
print (date) -- Jun 21 06:25:07
print (ip)   -- 206.221.177.2
```

See the [Lua demo online](https://ideone.com/2uASKu).

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(%w+ %d+ %d%d:%d%d:%d%d)` - Capturing group #1 (note its value will get assigned to `date`, the first var on the left hand side): 1+ alphanumerics, space, 1+ digits, space, 2 digits, `:`, 2 digits, `:` and 2 digits
- `.* DROP .* SRC=`  - literal string
- `(%S+)`  - Capturing group #2 (note its value will get assigned to `ip`, the second var on the left hand side): 1 or more non-whitespace chars.

Just remember that when there are capturing groups in a Lua pattern, the `string.match` function will return all of them. This is very handy.